# Find a Borel set $F$ such that $\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{m_N(F \cap B_k(x))}{m_N(B_k(x))}$ does not exist at some $x$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $F$ a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and we define, if exists,
>
> $$ D_F(x) := \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{m_N(F \cap B_k(x))}{m_N(B_k(x))}, $$
>
> where $B_k(x)$ is the open ball of radius $k$ and center $x$.
>
> **Problem.** Find a Borel set $F$ such that $D_F(x)$ does not exists at some point $x$.

I hope that someone can help me to find a solution. Here is [the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVIrD.jpg).

Comment: You might want to turn the page around; better still, convert it to MathJax.

Comment: I changed both the title and the body of the question so that it better reads. Also, we strongly recommend you to provide your own attempts, ideas, background or contexts. This helps other users provide better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $r_n, \alpha_n$ so that

1. $\alpha_n \in (0, 1)$ for all $n$ and $\alpha_n$ does not converge as $n\to\infty$.
2. $0 < r_{n+1} < \alpha_n r_n$ and $r_{n+1}/(\alpha_n r_n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Now define $F$ by $F = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n$, where $F_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N : \alpha_n r_n \leq \|x\| \leq r_n \}$. In other words, $F$ is a disjoint union of concentric annuli with extremely different scales $r_n$ and relative thickness $\alpha_n$. Then

$$ 1-\alpha_n^N = \frac{m_N(F_n)}{m_N(B_{r_n}(0))} \leq \frac{m_N(F \cap B_{r_n}(0))}{m_N(B_{r_n}(0))}, $$

and likewise,

$$ \frac{m_N(F \cap B_{r_n}(0))}{m_N(B_{r_n}(0))} \leq \frac{m_N(F_n) + m_N(B_{r_{n+1}}(0))}{m_N(B_{r_n}(0))} = 1-\alpha_n^N + \left( \frac{r_{n+1}}{\alpha_n r_n} \right)^N. $$

So if $D_F(0)$ exists, then it must follow that $1-\alpha_n^N$ converge, which is impossible by the assumption.